# Crash when trying to print the value at the root of a binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Simple enough program so far: a binary tree made up of nodes containing an integer value, and a pointer to the left and right branch of the node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} Node;

void insert(Node *root, int val);

int main(void){
    Node *root = NULL;

    insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 3);

    printf("%d\n", root->val);


    return 0;
}

void insert(Node *root, int val){
    if(root == NULL){ // Create tree if root is empty
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        root->val = val;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    } else if(val < root->val){ // branch to left of tree if new value is less than root value
        if(root->left == NULL){
            root->left = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        }

        root->left->val = val;
    } else if(val > root->val){ // branch to right of tree if new value is greater than root value
        if(root->right == NULL){
            root->right = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        }

        root->right->val = val;
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, the insertion goes fine. I can input both 5 and 3 (arbitrary) fine. But I can't print out the value '5' that should be in root->val? The program just completely crashes. Have I overlooked something?

Comment: Try printing the pointer value of `root` after the first `insert()` - it isn't what you think....

Comment: I appear to have goofed.

Comment: One way you goofed was not doing research.  About half of all linked-list/tree posts on SO have this 'only updates local vars'   problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the signature of `insert`:

```
void insert(Node *root, int val);
```

It cannot possibly take `NULL` for the `root` parameter, because it has no way to communicate back the change that happens to it inside the function. Any modifications to `root` inside `insert` remain local to `insert`, because pointers are passed by value, i.e. *copied*.

You have two general choices for a good signature:

- Make `insert` return the new `root`, i.e. `Node *c` If you use this approach, the callers will need to make calls as follows: `root = insert(root, 5);` or
- Pass `Node**` instead of `Node*`, i.e. `void insert(Node **root, int val);` If you use this approach, the callers will need to make calls as follows: `insert(&root, 5)`. Of course the implementation of `insert` will need to change as well, because an extra level of indirection requires an additional dereference.

Comment: Thank you. I need to brush up on scope and memory it seems.

Comment: I think you need to brush up on [pass by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value); *scope and memory* seem orthogonal.